# Javascript create own library like jquery

Tags: javascript, typescript, prototype-programming

I'm trying to create a library and i want to achieve something like JQuery, when we type `$(selector).` then the IDE will show a list of jquery method like `css` or `content` or etc.

So i created a few function in `library.js` like below:

```
const methodA = function(){
  //...logic
}

const methodB = function(x,y){
  //...internalMethod1()
}

const methodC = function(){
  // return smtg...
}

const internalMethod1 = function(){
  // return smtg...
}
```

Then at the end i declared:

```
var library_object = {
  a: methodA,
  b: methodB,
  c: methodC
}
window.$tr = library_object
```

At another `script.js`, i call the function like below:

```
$tr.b("abc","123")
```

My question is:
1) Am i doing it right? The best practice, avoid possible of overwritten, etc.

2) How do i make it callable like `$tr().b("abc","123")` instead?

3) Is there anything else i need to do to let mainstream IDE(visual studio code) know the possible function, especially when imported the js file typescript code.

Thank you.

Comment: 1) you're writing yet another jQuery clone; you literally say so. Why do you want to reinvent the wheel? 2) Why would you want that? What benefit do you think you'll get just by calling a function? 3) When you write JS and you want to import it to TS you should add a [Definition File](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html)

Comment: Want to make it more easier to use and make the kind of "autocomplete". So when user type `$tr.` then it will have a list of suggested method, instead of go open the `library.js` and go look at the function one by one which some of it is internal method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm just gonna answer your second question since its the only one i'm sure of:

to make it callable you could do something like this

```
window.$tr = function(){
  return library_object;
}
```